# In a power query, date should be picked up dynamically from a worksheet

Tags: excel

I have a power query in excel, which pulls data from a website. That data is dependent on a date. Right now, I have to manually change the date every week. I want the date to be picked up from cell C43 in worksheet named Dump. What changes should be done to the query? Below is the code. If I want to run this from today, I have to change the date from 20-Sept-23 to 27-Sept-23. This needs to be done dynamically as I have formulated the date 27-Sept-23 in cell C43 of worksheet Dump.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78uwC.png)

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY", [Headers=[#"Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate", #"Accept-Language"="en-US,en", #"User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.206"]])),
    records = Source[records],
    data = records[data],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"strikePrice", "expiryDate", "PE", "CE"}, {"strikePrice", "expiryDate", "PE", "CE"}),
    #"SelectedDate" =  Text.Split(Text.From((Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="BNFDump"]}[Content][Column1]{0}))," "){0},
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Column1", each [expiryDate] = #"SelectedDate",
    #"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each [expiryDate] = #"SelectedDate",
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows2", each [expiryDate] = #"SelectedDate",
    #"Expanded CE" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "CE", {"openInterest", "changeinOpenInterest", "impliedVolatility", "lastPrice", "change", "underlyingValue"}, {"CE.openInterest", "CE.changeinOpenInterest", "CE.impliedVolatility", "CE.lastPrice", "CE.change", "CE.underlyingValue"}),
    #"Expanded PE" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded CE", "PE", {"openInterest", "changeinOpenInterest", "impliedVolatility", "lastPrice", "change", "underlyingValue"}, {"PE.openInterest", "PE.changeinOpenInterest", "PE.impliedVolatility", "PE.lastPrice", "PE.change", "PE.underlyingValue"})
in
    #"Expanded PE"
```

I have not tried anything as I have no idea how to proceed.

[Expiry Date Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyNc3.png)

[Selected Date Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ogL3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Define cell C43 as `Dump` (update if needed)

[image]

- Select cell C43, Data>From Table/Range [Ribbon]
- In PQ editor, click `Close & Load to`, load it with `Only create connection`

Get a query named `Dump`.

Replace all date with `Text.From(List.First(Dump[Column1]))`.

```js
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY", [Headers=[#"Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate", #"Accept-Language"="en-US,en", #"User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.206"]])),
    records = Source[records],
    data = records[data],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"strikePrice", "expiryDate", "PE", "CE"}, {"strikePrice", "expiryDate", "PE", "CE"}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Column1", each [expiryDate] = Text.From(List.First(Dump[Column1]))),
    #"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each [expiryDate] = Text.From(List.First(Dump[Column1]))),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows2", each [expiryDate] = Text.From(List.First(Dump[Column1]))),
    #"Expanded CE" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "CE", {"openInterest", "changeinOpenInterest", "impliedVolatility", "lastPrice", "change", "underlyingValue"}, {"CE.openInterest", "CE.changeinOpenInterest", "CE.impliedVolatility", "CE.lastPrice", "CE.change", "CE.underlyingValue"}),
    #"Expanded PE" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded CE", "PE", {"openInterest", "changeinOpenInterest", "impliedVolatility", "lastPrice", "change", "underlyingValue"}, {"PE.openInterest", "PE.changeinOpenInterest", "PE.impliedVolatility", "PE.lastPrice", "PE.change", "PE.underlyingValue"})
in
    #"Expanded PE"
```

Update C43 and refresh your query to get the filtered data.

---

**Update**

If you prefer to obtain the result w/o extra query, please try

```js
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY", [Headers=[#"Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate", #"Accept-Language"="en-US,en", #"User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.206"]])),
    records = Source[records],
    data = records[data],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"strikePrice", "expiryDate", "PE", "CE"}, {"strikePrice", "expiryDate", "PE", "CE"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column1",{{"expiryDate", type date}}),
    #"SelectedDate" =  Table.TransformColumnTypes(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="BNFDump"]}[Content],{{"Column1", type date}})[Column1]{0},
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [expiryDate] = #"SelectedDate"),
    #"Expanded CE" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "CE", {"openInterest", "changeinOpenInterest", "impliedVolatility", "lastPrice", "change", "underlyingValue"}, {"CE.openInterest", "CE.changeinOpenInterest", "CE.impliedVolatility", "CE.lastPrice", "CE.change", "CE.underlyingValue"}),
    #"Expanded PE" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded CE", "PE", {"openInterest", "changeinOpenInterest", "impliedVolatility", "lastPrice", "change", "underlyingValue"}, {"PE.openInterest", "PE.changeinOpenInterest", "PE.impliedVolatility", "PE.lastPrice", "PE.change", "PE.underlyingValue"})
in
    #"Expanded PE"
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. In trying the first method, I get error " The column 'Column 1' of the table was not found.
Second method gives error 'We could not find excel table named 'Dump'.

Comment: Please make sure define the name `Dump`. I have loaded a screenshot and updated the code2.

Comment: I have named C43 as BNFDump as I have another cell to pull date from. However, now getting error Expression.SyntaxError: Token ',' expected. Attached screenshot in the main question.

Comment: Any name works. I guess line 7~9 miss a `)` before comma. Please update the code in OP if it is not the bug.

Comment: LIne 12 was missing a comma. Fixed that and now the error is Expression.SyntaxError: Token Literal expected. Code added in OP.

Comment: Remove the last comma from Line 12. The code line before `in` should not end with a comma.

Comment: No syntax errors this time. But the query does not load anything now. This happens when the date is incorrect. However, the date and the format in C43 is the same as the one entered manually.

Comment: Please refer to the last section of my reply.

Comment: Back to the Expression.SyntaxError: Token ',' expected error. Updated code posted in OP. Seems like we are just going around in circle of error.

Comment: lines 8~10 miss a `)` before comma. Pls carefully update the code.

Comment: No syntax errors this time. But still not able to pull the data and load table. I have updated the code with Text.Split. The format of the date in C43 is dd-mmm-yyyy.

Comment: Cell's date format doesn't affect the result of PQ. You should check #"SelectedDate" in PQ editor. Make sure it has same format with [expiryDate] column.

Comment: Updated 2 screenshots in OP. I really appreciate your help on this. Thank you!

Comment: I have updated the code and removed duplicated lines. It is tested with Excel 365. I would suggest that you use the whole solution ( the code in `Update` section).

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! That worked. You have no idea how grateful I am for your assistance!